# Is it possible to halt xterm scrolling while the program is running

Tags: linux, terminal, scrolling, xterm

I am trying to make xterm to meet my criteria for a terminal emulator. Most of the features I want are built into xterm but there is one that I can not get working. I'd like to ask if someone knows if it is possible with xterm or not.

So, is it possible to NOT scroll the contents of the xterm window while the program underneath is running and producing an output? I.e., the contents of the xterm window would be static.

There are similar questions but none I found considers this exact issue. To be clear, I am not asking to prevent scrolling down when the program outputs something (`scrollTtyOutput` option). I am also not asking how to halt the terminal window AND the program with software flow controls `C-s` and `C-q`. Also, for example, piping to less is not a suggestion I am seeking. I'd like to know if the feature described above is implemented in xterm or if there exists some kind of hack that produce the same outcome.

I am not familiar with the internals of xterm but let us assume it works something as follows:
There's an output buffer (for scrolling) lets say 1000 lines and some index variable i that contains the row number of the last visible row. Lets say we have a window of 40 rows scrolled so the rows 50-10 are shown (i=10). Assuming the program running in xterm outputs 5 rows, we now see the rows of same indices 50-10 but their contents are scrolled 5 rows. This is how xterm appears to work. It shows the same rows (in terms of offset) if you are not scrolling the window. What I would like is that the offset variable i would increment as new rows are printed, resulting in a static view of the terminal window.

Answer (score 1):

Starting the terminal with

```
xterm -si
```

suppresses scrolling. However, in case you want at one point see the end of the output as well, adding `-sk` would make sense. This option causes to a scrolling on the bottom of the screen, when you press any key. Of course this means that you have to decide on this behaviour by the time `xterm` is started. You can not turn on and off `-si` for a terminal which is already running.

Comment: First of all, you CAN turn -si option (scrollTtyOutput) on and off while xterm is running. Secondly, this does not answer the question. This option, which I specifically mentioned in the question, does not enable the described feature.